# JFileChooser redirection when a user has no access

Tags: java, jfilechooser

Is there a way to detect if the user has access to the path the JFileChooser is set to?

The default implementation seems to redirect to the default path which is Documents folder. I'd like to open a message box instead of the `Documents` folder.

Comment: Have you tried the methods in the [`Files` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isReadable%28java.nio.file.Path%29)?

Comment: @RealSkeptic This works perfectly, didn't know about those methods, thanks